# Reverse the entries in an HTML table

Tags: html

I have a webpage on our intranet with a table,

I have approx 10k records on it , is there a quick easy way to turn the whole table upside down (e.g. at the moment it goes 1 , 2 , 3 ) how can I change it to go 10000, 9999, 9998 ?

Comment: Where are you getting the records information? Are you getting it from a database like MySQL? if so there are ways to rearrange the information before you present it.

Comment: One time? Excel would work fine.

Comment: I have done it all in HTML <td> <tr> style

Comment: Yes, the end product is HTML but what _generates_ the table?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what is available to you, you can do it one of two ways: **server-side** or **client-side**.

Server-side of course depends on what technologies are available to you (e.g. PHP), and a solution of that sort will be simply reversing the beginning the ending indexes of whatever function / loop that generates the table.

Alternatively, you can use Javascript / jQuery in a client-side solution. In your case, a plugin much like this one may be your best bet:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Good luck!